# Using count distinct to find records with 2 or more different values in a field

Tags: sql, oracle, count, aggregate-functions

I have a simple question: How can I use Count(Distinct) in SQL (Oracle to be exact) to return only the rows where there are two or more different values in a given field.

This is easier understood by example:

```
ACCOUNT     SALESMAN
123         Abc
123         Abc

246         Abc
246         Def
246         Def

369         Hij

456         Abc
456         Def
```

In this example, the only Accounts with 2 **different** sales reps would be 246 and 456, and thus, I'd want the query's result to just show the the accounts shared by 2 or more salesmen:

```
ACCOUNT     SALESMAN
246         Abc
246         Def
456         Abc
456         Def
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select users have more than one distinct records in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237740/select-users-have-more-than-one-distinct-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `having` :

```
select distinct account,salesman 
from MyTable where account in
(
    select account
    from MyTable
    group by account
    having count(distinct salesman) >= 2
)
order by 1,2
```

Here is a [demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9898/1/0).

Comment: This is not right! If you are grouping by salesman `count(distinct salesman)` will always be 1, so this query will **never** return any results. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e047/1)

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer has indicated you need to use `HAVING`, but not in the manner indicated. You need to join back to the original table after using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT T.Account, T.SalesMan
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Account
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY Account
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SalesMan) > 1
        ) Dupes
            ON Dupes.Account = T.Account
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e047/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple GROUP BY/HAVING query:

```
select account
from t
group by account
having count(distinct salesperson) > 1
```

This returns the *accounts*, so the result is different from what you specify.  One way to get the sales people is to use listagg:

```
select account, listagg(salesperson, ',')
from t
group by account
having count(distinct salesperson) > 1
```

Otherwise, Gareth's answer returns the results the way you specified in the question.

Comment: How would you add another column to this using a sub query?

select p.account, p.listagg(salesperson, ',')
, (select address from acct_details where account = p.account)
from table p
group by p.account
having count(distinct p.salesperson) > 1