# select users have more than one distinct records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

For a table that holds the records of user's webpages visiting behavior, how can I select users that visit more than one webpages.

The structure of this tables is:

```
userId        webpageId       visitTime
  0              123            ...
  0              124            ...
  1              123            ...
 ...             ...            ...
```

I can count using:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) AS count FROM visits GROUP BY userId;
```

It gives me the result like:

```
userId          count
  0               2
  1               1
  2               6
 ...             ...
```

How can I excute query that gives me the final result like:

```
userId
  0
  2
 ...
```

each is user that visit more than one DISTINCT webpages

Answer (score 36, accepted):

just add having clause

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) AS count 
FROM visits 
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) > 1
```

but if you only what the `ID`

```
SELECT userId
FROM visits 
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/049e0/1)

the reason why you are filtering on `HAVING` clause and not on `WHERE` is because, `WHERE` clause cannot support columns that where *aggregated*.

Comment: btw: Can I use alias 'count' in HAVING clause?

Comment: @zoujyjs yes `HAVING` clause supports alias already.. see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/049e0/4

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) AS count FROM visits GROUP BY userId
having COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) > 1
```

More: [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

While `HAVING` is a good approach in this case, remember that queries can be nested:

```
SELECT userId, pageCount
FROM (
    SELECT userId, COUNT(DISTINCT webpageId) AS pageCount
    FROM visits 
    GROUP BY userId) AS n
WHERE pageCount > 1
```

The actual query plans may differ, especially if `HAVING` is an optimized case, but there is no reason why the plans must be different. (Compare plans on the specific RDBMS/version if it is an issue or concern.)