# How to get an ID associated with at least all contents?

Tags: sql

Suppose we have the database:

```
-----------
| A -|- B |
|----|----|
| 1  |  1 |
| 1  |  2 |
| 2  |  1 |
-----------
```

Where `A` and `B` is the primary key. Suppose we want to get all `A`s that contain the elements in `B` of 1 and 2.

```
SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B = 1 AND B = 2;
```

The above fails because it never holds true as the query is only for a single record.

```
SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B = 1 OR B = 2;
```

Works but erroneously includes the primary key value 2, which only maps to 1 in `B`, and not both 1 and 2 in `B`.

Comment: A is a foreign key maybe?

Comment: Fixed that. A and B are now primary keys.

Comment: You mean (A, B) is now the one and only primary key... (Remove pk part from question, and you'll not have to answer any more questions about it!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [select users have more than one distinct records in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237740/select-users-have-more-than-one-distinct-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` solution, return all a's that have more than 1 different b value in (1,2):

```
select a from table
where b in (1,2)
group by a
having count(distinct b) > 1
```

Or, `JOIN` solution:

```
select distinct a
from (select a from table where b = 1) t1
join (select a from table where b = 2) t2
  on t1.a = t2.a
```

Or an `INTERSECT` solution:

```
select a from table where b = 1
intersect
select a from table where b = 2
```

**Edit:**

`GROUP BY` query that *perhaps* is faster then the `HAVING count distinct` version:

```
select a from table
where b in (1,2)
group by a
having max(b) <> min(b)
```

Comment: Made this the answer due to its scalability. Unfortunately MySQL does not support INTERSECT. Anyhow, the `GROUP BY` solution is scalable and one can easily generate code for this query based on the amount of matches (1 to n).

Comment: Didn't know it was MySQL. Can't you tag mysql?

Comment: @jarlh: Correct me if I am wrong, but I was not explicitly trying to get it to question with MySQL in mind. I am working with MySQL, yes, but I would like to know the general way/method of performing the operation in SQL. So I think it's not necessary.

Comment: Do whatever you want. But dbms products may optimize things in different ways, so in some cases a query can run fast with one dbms and slow with another dbms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group by method from jarlh or make a Join with a 'distinct':

```
select distinct a
from (select a from table where b = 1) t1
join (select a from table where b = 2) t2
  on t1.a = t2.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (assuming that you need to filter by the specific IDs in B.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM Table AS T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table WHERE Table.A = T.A and B = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Table WHERE Table.A = T.A and B = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A
FROM Table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table t1
    WHERE t1.A = Table.A 
        AND t1.B = 1
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table t2 
    WHERE t2.A = Table.A 
        AND t2.B = 2
)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer more understandable for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

- `A` cannot be the primary key here, since the column contains duplicates.
- One possible solution:

  `SELECT * FROM (SELECT A, group_concat(B, ',') AS C FROM tab GROUP BY A) s WHERE s.C = "1,2";`