# Retrieving existing record based on its many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a simple threaded instant messaging system built from the following schema:

[image: Schema]

A thread can contain two or more users, and users can belong to many threads. When a user tries to create a new thread, I need to check if an existing thread already exists between the users (specified by ID), and return the existing thread. I should only return the existing thread if the users I specify are the **only** users in that thread.

Normally, I'd use a query like this:

```
select distinct t.* from threads t
inner join thread_users tu on tu.thread_id = t.id
where tu.user_id in (1, 2);
```

However, this query will return threads where the two users (ID `1` and `2`) are not the **only** users in that thread. What I really need is something like an `only in (1, 2)` clause.

How can I achieve the same thing as a `where only in` clause?

Edit: Came up with this from a related question that appeared in the sidebar after I posted:

```
select t.* from threads t
inner join thread_users tu on tu.thread_id = t.id
where tu.user_id in (1, 2)
having count(distinct tu.user_id) = 2;
```

This *seems* to work, but I might be missing an edge case which I haven't accounted for in my database data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an ID associated with at least all contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137672/how-to-get-an-id-associated-with-at-least-all-contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-a set subquery:  you are looking for sets of users within a thread.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`, because that is a very flexible method.  I think the following does what you want:

```
select t.*
from threads t join
     thread_users tu
     on t.id = tu.thread_id
group by t.id
having sum(tu.user_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(tu.user_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(tu.user_id not in (1, 2)) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon. I think I may have found a solution which has less `having` statements, I've edited it into my question. Is there certain edge cases that your query accounts for that mine doesn't?

Comment: @JohnDorean . . . It doesn't seem to return what you want.  If users 1, 2, and 3 are in a thread, my query will not return the thread.  Yours will.

Comment: Ah, I got mixed up with my test data. It was indeed returning the wrong thread. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you thread ideas that have both users `1` and `2` and only those users:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM threads t join
     thread_users tu
     on t.id = tu.thread_id
GROUP by t.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct user_id) = 2
    AND SUM (CASE WHEN user_id NOT IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: This is actually returning me two threads on my test schema when it should only return one. I have two threads, the first has users `1`, `2`, `3` and the second has users `1` and `2` which is the thread that I would like to return.

Comment: You are right, there should be two conditions for exclusion for (1,2,3) case. updated the answer.