# SQL select row where (this column has many different values in the other)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select rows where some precise column has different values while another precise column has the same value.

Exemple :

```
COLUMN_A  |  COLUMN_B
__________|___________
          |
1         |   2002
1         |   2002
2         |   2001
2         |   2007
3         |   2010
3         |   2010
```

Now, suppose I want to know which Rows has the same A but different B, the query would return the rows

```
2         |   2001
2         |   2007
```

or just

```
2
```

as long as I know which one is it ...

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT DISTINCT etc.

Comment: I would go with the self join or Exists query.. `group by having distinct count` is probably the worst performance wise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select users have more than one distinct records in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237740/select-users-have-more-than-one-distinct-records-in-mysql)

Comment: @JamieD77 Possibly, but what if there are more than two different values in COLUMN_B? `Count Distinct` would handle it fine whereas `Join` would require `Distinct` of it's own. With multiple different values `Join` turns into Cartesian product.

Comment: @Y.B.  I would have used EXISTS personally... I didnt put much thought into the self join :)

Comment: @Y.B.  this is the only reason i say that http://i.stack.imgur.com/XsaBU.png

Comment: @JamieD77 I agree. Execution plan for the Lamak's first suggestion with `HAVING MIN(COLUMN_B) <> MAX(COLUMN_B)` looks good too. In defense of `Count Distinct` I can only say that it's easier to convert to "more than N" and I find it easier to understand (/ debug / support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the case for Count(**Distinct** *ColumnName*). It ensures that only unique values are taken into account.

```
With Src As (
    Select *
    From (Values
        (1, 2002),
        (1, 2002),
        (2, 2001),
        (2, 2007),
        (3, 2010),
        (3, 2010)
    ) V (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
)
Select *
From Src
Where COLUMN_A In (
    Select COLUMN_A
    From Src
    Group By COLUMN_A
    Having Count(Distinct COLUMN_B) > 1 --<- "More than one unique value" condition
    )
```

---

```
COLUMN_A    COLUMN_B
       2        2001
       2        2007
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A  
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY COLUMN_A  
HAVING MIN(COLUMN_B) <> MAX(COLUMN_B);
```

Another way can be using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
             WHERE COLUMN_A = A.COLUMN_A
             AND COLUMN_B <> A.COLUMN_B);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is without GROUPing:

```
SELECT x.column_a, x.column_b, y.column_b
  FROM table_name x
  JOIN table_name y
    ON ( x.column_a = y.column_a AND x.column_b <> y.column_b )
```

You just join the table to itself, and provide the conditions you are looking for.